# how to generate two columns with a 2019 year date and each date having time slot 9.00 am to 8.00 pm?

Tags: r

Create 2 columns in R with one column having 2019 date and in second column time, which has time slot 9.00AM to 8PM with 1 hour gap. So in total for  a date we should have 11 columns. For example(below)

[image]

Comment: Should we have 11 rows and 2 columns? An expected result would be helpful

Comment: yeah for a date we must have only 11 rows with time slot, which in total makes 2 column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, what is your desired column type, so you have different options below :-)

Here comes my solution:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
start <- ymd_hms("2019-05-01 09:00:00")
end <- start + hm("11:00")

tibble(timestamp = seq.POSIXt(start, end,  by = 3600)) %>% 
  mutate(day = date(timestamp),
         time = strftime(timestamp, format="%H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  select(day, time, timestamp)

  day        time     timestamp          
   <date>     <chr>    <dttm>             
 1 2019-05-01 09:00:00 2019-05-01 09:00:00
 2 2019-05-01 10:00:00 2019-05-01 10:00:00
 3 2019-05-01 11:00:00 2019-05-01 11:00:00
 4 2019-05-01 12:00:00 2019-05-01 12:00:00
 5 2019-05-01 13:00:00 2019-05-01 13:00:00
 6 2019-05-01 14:00:00 2019-05-01 14:00:00
 7 2019-05-01 15:00:00 2019-05-01 15:00:00
 8 2019-05-01 16:00:00 2019-05-01 16:00:00
 9 2019-05-01 17:00:00 2019-05-01 17:00:00
10 2019-05-01 18:00:00 2019-05-01 18:00:00
11 2019-05-01 19:00:00 2019-05-01 19:00:00
12 2019-05-01 20:00:00 2019-05-01 20:00:00
```

Regards
Paweł

Answer (score 0):

A random date range:

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 6, Sys.Date(), 1)
)

df <- merge(df,expand.grid(date = df$date, time = 9:20))
df <- df[order(df$date, df$time), ]
df$time <- sprintf("%02i:00", df$time)
```